# How can I create a Quora or Stack Exchange facility without using a specialist theme?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, stackoverflow

I would like to implement a section of my site that can be used for Q&A, like Quora or the SE sites. So far, the only solution I can find is to use a specialist theme, which I don't want to do - I want the feature to be part of an existing site.

What methods or solutions can I use that might work for me in this instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make that part of my existing site, I'd use [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types), Say a post type as `QA` and registered users can do post( ask questions) and others can comment(give answers). Using the [Roles and Capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) feature of wordpress we can create moderators/editors/users for  question answer section.

We can configure wordpress to accept posts of that post-type (`QA`) to be submitted on front-end (with form on ask question page) and the wordpress comment system is ready to use as it is.

We can create a [wordpress query with different parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) to show result as we want.

finally, the ratings can be handled by plugins, there are plenty of good plugins available in [Wordpress plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) to start with.

> #### NOTE -
>
> [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) uses some in-house developed systems, It is not an easy task to replicate it in your wordpress site ( specially the realtime part ). And the feature you might get from a full functional forum software is possible to replicate in Wordpress but very difficult.

*For light weight QA forum with less feature I'd recommend using this technique*

Answer (score 1):

I would go the route of an existing plugin if you're not wanting to do all of the development yourself and wanting to integrate Q&A into an existing site.

There are several  WordPress plugins that will give you functionality like Quora, StackExchange, etc. - without the need for a completely new or independent theme:

- [10+ Question & Answer WordPress plugins](http://postashio.com/question-answer-wordpress-plugins/)

I've used a couple of them and have had no issues or problems integrating them into existing sites and/or blogs.